# Is there a google talk client for Google Apps for Domains?

Tags: google-workspace, google-talk

We use the free google apps for domains. I was wondering if and how to use the GTalk client for google apps for domains ?

I can currently use my gmail ID with gtalk but if I want to use my google apps for domains ID on Gtalk, how do I do that ? Is that supported ?

thank you,

BR,
~A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use my google apps for
>   domains ID on Gtalk, how do I do that
>   ? Is that supported ?

Yes, login username would be `<username>@<domain>`

I use it.

Comment: @sathya, is gtalk a webapp or a locally-installed program?

Comment: gtalk : it is a thick client app. It also is available as part of gmail.

Comment: @quack quixote : Both actually - there's a standalone app ( http://google.com/talk ) as well as the webclient built-into Gmail/Gmail for Apps

Comment: Don't forget that you need to generate an application specific password for the client if you're using 2-factor authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever tried using the Google Talk client with Apps, but Google has a [KB article](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49147) about using the Pidgin IM client to connect to Talk services. I've used Pidgin before, and actually prefer it to Google Talk, so you may want to try that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **OS X** you can [use iChat](http://support.google.com/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24076) to connect to Google talk. Though I strongly recommend the free chat client [Adium](http://adium.im/)

Answer (score 0):

I use digsby, an IM client which support multiple login with different accounts. It supports Gtalk/Gmail accounts and can use Google Apps logins also.

http://www.digsby.com